# unable to apply toggleclass for bg after js script execution

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have this button on a page ...

```
<div id="bgtoggle">
</div>
```

i also have this script on the index page

```
 <script>
         $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#bgtoggle").click(function () {
        $(".metro").toggleClass("bgcolorchange");
    });
});</script>
```

the class bgcolorchange has this css

```
.bgcolorchange {
    background-image: url("../images/mthc/music-therapy-imageN.jpg");
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  overflow : hidden ;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    z-index:3000;
}
```

this is great because where .metro is the class of the body it basically changes the img on button click.... however....

i also have this script for a menu item that changes the bg img as well..

```
$('.fa-question-circle').parent().on('click', function () {
      $(".metro").css('background-image','url('+"images/mthc/image2.jpg"+')');
```

trouble is once the above script executes and fa-questin-circle is clicked you can no longer use the toggle it doesn't overlay the img contained in bgtoggle class. I have tried z-index and all that jazz but don't know what is happening. why is this ?

EDIT :- the html for the fa-questino-circle

```
<div id="menu">
            <nav>
                <h2><i class="fa"></i>HOME</h2>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-question-circle"></i>
```

Comment: Please provide a working jsFiddle. I have no idea of where `.fa-question-circle` is in your DOM, for example.

Comment: having troble with jsfiddle as it is getting the img for that icon from font-awesome  i will add the html for that bit though sorry

Comment: Just replace the font awesome icon with some random letter in the fiddle. After all, it's intended to be only a minimal working example :)

Comment: hmm ok i will try hang on

Comment: here ya go best i can do http://jsfiddle.net/95cnk37g/6/

Comment: so what do think the problem might be ????

Comment: Working on it. Will post the answer soon :)

Comment: I think when you apply the background-image directly to the control it's like to set a css attribute in control, that overrides the image in your .bgcolorchange class.
Try to add a class with the image you want to change with background-image attribute and use toogleClass with this class instead of directly set the background-image attribute.
I updated the fiddle, just check out, may help you:
http://jsfiddle.net/95cnk37g/6/

Comment: so in effect i should be saying (.metro).addclass(otherbgcolor) instead of the (.metro).css(background-image....

Comment: i updated the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/95cnk37g/8/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just got it working: [see here](http://jsfiddle.net/95cnk37g/9/). There were two problems here.

The first one is that when you add the `bgcolorchange` class, its `background-image` wasn't being considered because the first class (`metro`) already had that property. So, I had to add the `!important` notation to it, thus being able to remove the `z-index` property which would bring you problems.

The second problem is that when you set the CSS via `.css` function, it is added as an inline style, which overrides that same property from CSS classes. This was solved by adding `$('.metro').css('background-image', '');` as the `#bgtoggle`'s click event's first line, to remove the inline style before toggling the BG class.

Please note that I had to use random images to actually show the code working.

Comment: ah right so by adding  $('.metro').css('background-image', ''); to the toggle button allows the change to happen then ?

Comment: Yep, because it removes the inline style which has higher priority than class properties. Don't forget the other changes I stated in my answer as well.

Comment: thanks for your help on this i will get back to it after my dinner :p